# Private Network with IPFS not working

Tags: distributed-system, ipfs

We have created 2 nodes using stranded ( https://ipfs.io/docs/install/)
Both are connected to the public network and working fine.
Now we are trying to create a Private Network with these 2 nodes as described below, but data is not getting synced on both nodes.
https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/experimental-features.md#private-networks

Below is the responce when we start daemon

```
$ipfs daemon --enable-pubsub-experiment

Initializing daemon...
Adjusting current ulimit to 2048...
Successfully raised file descriptor limit to 2048.
Swarm is limited to private network of peers with the swarm key
Swarm key fingerprint: 5c9869c16230b2b24f66f89a519043d1
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip6/::1/tcp/4001
API server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001
Gateway (readonly) server listening on /ip4/1127.0.0.1/tcp/8080
Daemon is ready
```

Comment: Issue resolved by adding the other nodes as a Bootstrap nodes during the daemon start.

Comment: Add this as a nice answer. It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions!

Answer (score 1):

I also meet same issue like above, when I try to create private network of ipfs

My resolution, In the First peers do this: 
1. after ipfs init, delete all exist bootstrap items

```
<code>ipfs bootstrap rm --all</code>
```

2. run

   `ipfs daemon &`
3. check self id：

   `ipfs id`

In "Addresses" session, the address were here.

4. copy the address to fellow command like：

   `ipfs bootstrap add /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmXrDENoDrzn4pmGYUS4wbPvPhYUkxDCa9ij7dK1VAMqKP
   ipfs bootstrap add /ip4/192.168.3.98/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmXrDENoDrzn4pmGYUS4wbPvPhYUkxDCa9ij7dK1VAMqKP
   ipfs bootstrap add /ip6/::1/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmXrDENoDrzn4pmGYUS4wbPvPhYUkxDCa9ij7dK1VAMqKP
   ipfs bootstrap add /ip4/192.168.9.56/tcp/60824/ipfs/QmXrDENoDrzn4pmGYUS4wbPvPhYUkxDCa9ij7dK1VAMqKP`

In the other peers do the 4.step.
After a while they are connected.

```
ipfs swarm peers
```

Hope to help more people to take less detours